# Trouble in Access VBA with variable calling from combo box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm very new to VBA and am making a mock program for calculating if someone is eligible for a home loan, but I'm having trouble with combo boxes containing numerical values passing their values over to variables used in the code, any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Elegibility_Calculator_Click()

    'Variables
    Dim crScore As Integer
    Dim yrIncome As Long
    Dim MINCRSCORE As Integer
    Dim MINYRINCOME As Long

    'Variable Values
    crScore = cbocrScore
    yrIncome = cboyrIncome
    MINCRSCORE = 650
    MINYRINCOME = 100000

    'Calculate Elegibility
    If crScore >= MINCRSCORE & yrIncome >= MINYRINCOME Then
    MsgBox "blah"
Else
    MsgBox "bad blah"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your If condition uses `&` which is for concatenation. Use logical operator `AND` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. Like I said, I'm very new, so i dont know much, but i really appreciate it.

Comment: Is accepted the check mark? And because I have less than 15 reputation my upvote wont show up.

Comment: Yes, check mark is Accepted indicator. Think one way to gain rep is to read the FAQ's. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask